# What is the main difference between " enterprise" blockchain and regular blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, privacy, private-blockchains, hyperledger

We have some blockchain-based cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin or Ethereum. On the other hand,  we have some blockchain-based frameworks such as [hyperledger](https://www.hyperledger.org/) and [R3](http://www.r3cev.com/) that are designed for businesses.

**Question**: What is an enterprise blockchain?

Is it right those permissioned (and/or private) frameworks (e.g. hyperledger and  R3) are considered as enterprise blockchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line between a blockchain and a distributed database (or ledger) is currently blurred (some would say deliberately so given the hype surrounding "blockchains" at the moment). R3 have recently concluded that it does not make sense to use a blockchain for their enterprise use case as financial institutions do not want to publish data on all their transactions to all nodes on the network. Therefore signed messages are exchanged bilaterally on R3's Corda. I am not an expert on Hyperledger but I think it is focusing predominantly on private or permissioned blockchains. These have a chain of blocks (that each contain a number of transactions) but access (ability to transact and verify transactions) is restricted to a finite number of participants. My personal opinion is that if there are transactions being batched into blocks, cryptographically attached to previous blocks and verified by all (or a subset of) nodes on a network then it should be considered a blockchain. Bitcoin and Ethereum are public blockchains. There are no restrictions in terms of those who can transact on it, view it or verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise blockchains are usually restricted to a consortium of companies or organizations--they are not open to everyone as are regular blockchains.

Enterprise blockchains usually do not use digital currency (bitcoin, for example). There are no miners to pay. Everyone is free to add to the blockchain (because the set of users are restricted). Yes, R3's Corda and the group of Hyperledger blockchain platforms (there are multiple independent Hypeerledger blockchain technologies) are enterprise blockchains.

Some people argue that an Enterprise blockchain is not really a blockchain in that it is restricted, has no digital currency, and no miners. But it still has a chain of blocks.

Sometimes a more general term "Digital Ledger Technology" (DLT) is used in lieu of "blockchain" to avoid arguments over what is a true blockchain.

Answer (score -1):

As a concept, It helps to have a industry specific blockchains like a banking consortium to make sure two companies are not providing the same service to the same individual. Perhaps to weed out fraudulent transactions

Or perhaps for a services industry specific blockchain to make sure all the parties in the industry keep their promise and dont go back on the promised services. Perhaps a reputation based blockchain. It works if the major player/players adopt the block chain concept. else there wont be many players. Or a trusted 3rd party setsup the platform and the major industry players join in

Comment: does this really answer: What is an enterprise blockchain?